# uninstallation of windows service fails sometimes forcing restart of the machine

Tags: c#, windows-services, packaging, setup-deployment

I am having trouble with uninstallation and reinstallation of windows service. sometimes when I uninstall using the MSI package for the service (even after stopping the service and closing the service management console), the service is not getting uninstalled and then if I run "installUtil", then the service is getting disabled, but not removed from the console. then if I try "sc delete service.exe", I get an error "service is marked for deletion". once this error occurs, the only option I have is to restart the workstation or the server wherever it is installed. sometimes it works fine and sometimes it doesn't uninstall properly. how can I ensure that the uninstall works always? why uninstall is so painful? during development, I need to reinstall the service several times to install new version of the service and it will be useful to easily reinstall the service without having to restart the machine. 
thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try uninstalling with the control panel instead of the msi or installutil? I always remove my services that way and have yet to encounter that issue.

Comment: I would guess at a thread that you're not always terminating when you get the OnStop() request.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into a similar problem when I was constantly installing, rebuilding, and uninstalling my service during testing.  I think it had to do with rebuilding the MSI before trying to uninstall the service.  Always uninstalling from the Add/Remove programs dialog should avoid this, but it's a bit of a hassle.  I ended up modifying my Wix setup project to do three things:

1. The MSI is setup to start/stop the service. One example [here](http://blog.tentaclesoftware.com/archive/2009/01/01/21.aspx).
2. Have a custom action to stop the install if the current version or a new version is already installed.  Based on [this](http://www.tramontana.co.hu/wix/lesson4.php#4.1) code.
3. Create an uninstall shortcut on the desktop. One example [here](http://robmensching.com/blog/posts/2007/4/27/How-to-create-an-uninstall-shortcut-and-pass-all-the).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your service is having some problem shutting down because it is suffering from an unhandled error. If there is a log, try to see if nothing is thrown there. Otherwise, I would add a log mechanism (log4net for example). If adding a logging mechanism is not an option, chezy525's solution seems the way to go.